# Java Array Index Out of Bound Exception 2

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I was trying to do a sorting class of matrices entries and I first put them into an array

```
 double[][] A ={{0,70,9},{1,3,4}};

    double[] vektori_per_sortim=new double[A.length*A[0].length];

    int k=0;

    for(int i=0; i!=A.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j!=A[0].length; j++)
        {
            vektori_per_sortim[k]=A[i][j];
            k++;
        }

    }
```

and then I tried to put them into the matrices again

```
int r=0;
  while(r!=vektori_per_sortim.length)
{
    for(int i=0; i!=vektori_per_sortim.length/A.length; i++)
     {
       for(int j=0; j!=vektori_per_sortim.length/A[0].length; j++)
       {
          A[i][j]=vektori_per_sortim[r];
          r++; 

        }

      }


}
```

but I get an error 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2

Can you please help me out with this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Most developers would use a debugger to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `i!=vektori_per_sortim.length/A.length`?

Comment: What line caused the error?

Comment: Let me guess - Your question was identical to a previous one, so you added a 2 to the title.  **That means don't ask it.**

Comment: @djechlin No, the 2 is the out of bounds index in the error.

Comment: If you can write this much code, then you can obviously debug also. So give a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you mixed up your dimensions, and tried to copy the 6 element vector into a 3x2 matrix rather than a 2x3 matrix.

You can tell because when you copy the values out of the matrix, `i` goes from `0` to `A.length`. When you copy them back in, `i` goes from `0` to `A[0].length` (= `vektori_per_sortim.length/A.length`).

You could switch the `i` and `j` conditions, but it would be way cleaner to simply use your first loops and reverse the copy inside them:

```
k=0;
for(int i=0; i!=A.length; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j!=A[0].length; j++)
    {
        A[i][j] = vektori_per_sortim[k];
        k++;
    }

}
```

Comment: You should probably use `k = 0;` at the beginning, otherwise the old value of k will be used.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That worked well. 

I had been messing with the lengths a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

You may want a different approach to putting the values back into the matrix. I would recommend iterating through the elements in the same way that you did to put them into the array, but copying them the other way this time. Try replacing the *second* code block with this:

```
int r = 0;
for(int i=0; i!=A.length; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j!=A[0].length; j++)
    {
        A[i][j] = vektori_per_sortim[r];
        r++;
    }

}
```